# Why my functions disappears from objects when I pass them? Angular, typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, function

I've been making a simple Casino Game, where user can buy for example profile pictures from the shop, all items are stored in array, it is looking like that:

```
shopItems = [
    {
      type: 'Profile Photo',
      name: 'Hugo',
      price: 50,
      bought: false,
      action: () => {
        this.profilePhotos[2].bought = true;
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'Profile Photo',
      name: 'Philips',
      price: 100,
      bought: false,
      action: () => {
        this.profilePhotos[3].bought = true;
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'Profile Photo',
      name: 'Michael',
      price: 200,
      bought: false,
      action: () => {
        this.profilePhotos[4].bought = true;
      },
    }
...
```

function to buy items:

```
 buyItem(shopItem) {
    console.log(shopItem)
    if (this.updatePoints() >= shopItem.price) {
      shopItem.bought = true
      shopItem.action()
    }
  }
```

^These two fragments of code are in profile.service.ts and this in profile.component.ts:

```
buyItem(shopItem) {
    console.log(shopItem)
    this.profileService.buyItem(shopItem)

  }
```

its being invoke when user clicks 'unlock' button (profile.component.html):

```
<div class="shop" *ngIf="shopOpened">

        <div class="shop-items">
            <div class="shop-item" *ngFor="let shopItem of shopItems">
                <div class="type">{{shopItem.type}}</div>
                <div class="name">{{shopItem.name}}</div>
                <div class="shop-item-price">{{shopItem.price}}</div>
                <div class="buy-button" (click)="buyItem(shopItem)" *ngIf="!shopItem.bought">UNLOCK</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="exit-button" (click)="toogleShopOpened()">EXIT</div>
    </div>
```

And here is the issue: Every time when I click UNLOCK, nothing happens, action() is not being invoked because it doesn't exist:
[image: there is no 'action']

I don't know if its relevant but here are places when I access local storage (profile.service.ts):

```
constructor() {
    this.getData()
  }
```

and in resetGame(): (resetGame is being invoke when the game is played first time as well)

```
resetGame(){
    this.saveData()
    this.getData()
}
```

```
saveData() {
    localStorage.setItem('profileService', JSON.stringify(this));
  }

  getData() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('profileService') !== null) {
      Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profileService')));
    }

  }
```

I've checked local storage and I can't see my functions as well:
[image]
just as if browser doesn't see 'action'.
I've tried two different browser and delete local storage, nothing helped.

Comment: I can't say I'm very familiar with Angular, but to me the issue seems to be that you're serializing the items as JSON. JSON doesn't have any notion of functions and thus `JSON.stringify` cannot serialize them. AFAIK it simply ignores them.

Comment: In addition to the above-mentioned (big) problem, those `action()` functions are all `=>` functions, so it's not clear what you expect `this` to be in the functions anyway. I think you need to reconsider how those functions are supposed to work; like, maybe instead of being functions, they can be simple objects that contain parameter information to a function external to the data structure.